# Доказательство знания секрета, переданного через третьего актора

Tags: криптография

Существует ли канонический или какой иной надежный подход к решению следующей проблемы:

-- три актора A, B, C

-- актор C передает актору A некое значение x(C)

-- актор A передает "что-то полезное" актору B с требованием вручить актору, доказавшему знание x(C)

-- актор C доказывает актору B знание x(C) и получает "что-то полезное".

общение идет по открытым каналам, но допустимы ограниченные обмены в закрытом режиме.

актор B не участвует в процессе предварительной договоренности между A и C

актор A не участвует в процессе общения между C и B при доказательстве знания x(C) и передаче полезной нагрузки.

Answer (score 1):

**Хэширование**

Чарли (C) передаёт Бобу (B) `hash(x(C))` либо в открытом виде, либо зашифрованное публичным ключом Боба `Enc(hash(x(C)), PubKey_B)`. Так как вероятность угадать хэш, не зная само значение, равна нулю, то знание хэша служит доказательством знания `x(C)`.

Если враги знают, что `x(C)` принимает небольшое число значений, то могут попытаться подобрать само значение, подслушав сообщение от Чарли к Бобу.

Шифрование публичным ключом означает, что только Боб сможет расшифровать это сообщение. Таким образом происходит защита от подслушивания и последующего перебора.

**Дискретный логарифм**

Второй вариант. Чарли и Боб договариваются использовать простое число `p` и начальное число `g`.  Чарли присылает Бобу значение `g^{x(C)} mod p`.

Надёжность этой схемы опирается на тот факт, что не существует эффективного алгоритма дискретного логарифма.

Эту схему можно реализовать на эллиптических кривых. Чарли и Боб выбирают кривую и начальную точку `G` на ней. Чарли присылает `x(C)*G`. Та же проблема дискретного логарифма.

Если каждый раз, когда нужно передать `x(C)`, выбирать разное начальное значение, то можно скрыть тот факт, что передаётся одно и то же число.

**Цифровая подпись**

Чарли вычисляет цифровую подпись `ECDSA(x(C), PrivKEy_C)` и отсылает её Бобу. Только подпись, без самого сообщения. Так как Боб знает `x(C)`, он может проверить цифровую подпись. Тут вам всё в одном - и хэширование, и дискретный логарифм, и nonce для защиты от перебора, атак повторного воспроизведения и обеспечения частичной конфиденциальности канала.